# Set margin with javascript and change it according to window width

Tags: javascript

This is probably very simple, but Java script is very new for me, and I couldn't figure out proper solution from examples found on the Web.

I am creatiing a Wordpress page. In my main menu after clicking "search" button, the search form opens. The margin of `#primary-manu` is beeing changed after clicking, that all menu elements fit. This piece of code is working perfectly:

```
$("#formButton").click(function(){
$("#formButton").hide();
    $("#searchform1").show();
$("#project-menu").css('margin-right', '70px'); 
});
```

But when the window with is max. `1074px`, `70px margin` is too much. I found, that I should pobably use `window.matchMedia`, but I can't figure out, how should I make it work. I came up with the following:

```
function changeMargin(x) {
      if (x.matches) { 
           #project-menu.style.marginRight = "40px";
             } else {
           #project-menu.style.marginRight = "70px";
           }
           }  


var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1074)")
changeMargin(x)
x.addListener(changeMargin)
```

But it just breaks the working `$("#formButton").click(function()`

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: `#project-menu` isn’t an element; it’s a selector, so use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector). `addListener` isn’t a method that exists on EventTargets. You probably mean [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). _“What is wrong with my code?”_ — use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. Looks like it’s mostly typos. Make sure to read the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use css syntax like `#project-menu.style.marginRight` in javascript. Your function with jQuery:

```
function changeMargin(x) {
    if (x.matches) { 
        $("#project-menu").css('margin-right', '40px'); 
    } else {
        $("#project-menu").css('margin-right', '70px'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to be responsive to window size changes, you probably want to target the [window 'resize' event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event):

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', changeMargin);
```

And there's no need to use `matchMedia()`, since `changeMargin()` only needs to know the current window width, which is simply `window.innerWidth`:

```js
const projectMenu = document.getElementById('project-menu');
function changeMargin () {
  projectMenu.style.marginRight = window.innerWidth > 1074 ? '40px' : '70px';
}
```

Finally, you need to set the margin when the page is first loaded, so target the [window 'load' event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', changeMargin);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking can and should be managed with CSS, not javascript, by using [media-queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

I'm using different numbers on `margin-right` just to showcase how it looks. Resize the browser window to see that the margin changes when the snippet has a width of 400px.

```css
#project-menu {
  margin-right: 170px;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  #project-menu {
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

.demo {
  height: 40px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;  
}
```

```html
<div id="project-menu" class="pink demo"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is, that the new margin-left value is added after clicking the button. I can't target it with media query.

Comment: Sure you can, if you add a class with a margin, instead of just changing the style.